# How to add customized property like 'test_key' inside Junit XML report through junit.xml.ejs file

Tags: xml, junit, report, customization

`We are running Nightwatch Automation test suite through CICD pipeline, Once finished it generates an junit.xml output file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testsuites tests="1" failures="0" name="UITests" time="12">
    <testsuite tests="1" failures="0" name="Test" time="232.9559440612793">
        <testcase classname="Test" name="test()" time="42.36027908325195">
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

However I want to be able to import my tests cases to our test case management tool. In order to do so I need to add a property to my junit.xml file. So the end result should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testsuites tests="1" failures="0" name="UITests" time="12">
    <testsuite tests="1" failures="0" name="Test" time="232.9559440612793">
        <testcase classname="Test" name="test()" time="42.36027908325195">
            <properties>
                <!-- using a custom "test_id" property -->
                <property name="test_key" value="{{should be extracted dynamically from test case name}}" />
            </properties>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Is there an easy way of realizing this, by for instance using (custom) annotations/properties?

We have junit.xml.ejs file where we have this above structure.`